# Angular - How to make router-outlet directive ignore query params

Tags: angular, routes, router-outlet

I have a routing.module.ts file that contains the following code:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    ...
    { path: ‘profile/:id’, component: ProfileComponent }
];
```

I have an app.component.ts file that contains the template:

```
<div class=“app-container”>
    <header></header>
    <div class=“body”>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to navigate to this site using a query param, e.g mysite.com/profile/1234?q=5, I get a 404 for mysite.com/profile/1234%3Fq%3D5

How do I make it so that the router-outlet doesn’t include the query parameter portion of the request?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials online pick one!!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `router.navigate()` method, try to pass the URL by first decoding it as

```
router.navigate([decodeURIComponent(url)]);
```

Activated Route does not encode the URL before accessing the parameters